US equivalent of the Microvitec Cub monitor
In the 8-bit computing era, UK schools acquired BBC Micros in a project sponsored by the BBC. The monitor typically used with these was the Microvitec Cub.
In the US, there was also a push to put computers in schools, the largest part of which was sponsored by Apple:
https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/how-you-wound-playing-em-oregon-trailem-computer-class-180959851/
https://americanhistory.si.edu/comphist/sj1.html
Basically, Apple gave away 100,000 Apple IIs to schools, after successfully lobbying for a law that let them offset some of the cost in tax deduction.
What monitor was typically used with those machines? And did Apple supply the monitors as part of the donation, or did the schools have to buy them separately?

much as I'm digging any Microvitec content, I suspect this has been asked before: Did Apple bundle a specific monitor with the Apple II+ for schools?

I don't know whether this was regional but all the Apple computers at schools in my area (northern Illinois) as a kid in the mid-80s had Amdek monitors, usually a 300A.
